# SQL conditionally update based on 2 different values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to update a field based on a `where IN  ()` clause but i also want the update the rest of the values using `WHERE NOT IN()`..For example:

```
UPDATE TABLE SET COLUMN1 = X WHERE COLUMN2 IN (1,2,3)
UPDATE TABLE SET COLUMN1 = Y WHERE COLUMN2 NOT IN (1,2,3)
```

To simply put it ,is there a way to combine these two queries?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
UPDATE 
  TABLE
SET 
  COLUMN1 = CASE WHEN COLUMN2 IN (1,2,3) THEN X ELSE Y END
```